# Codenameone text fields not getting cleared after exiting the aap

Tags: runtime, runtime-error, codenameone, hybrid-mobile-app

I need your help with my app, the scenario goes as follows:

> 1. Start the app
> 2. Enter details like password and all
> 3. Exit the app after that

When I again start the app, I want all fields to be blank

The text i entered do not get clear .I have not given any specific instruction for text to not get clear.

Comment: Do you mean exit the app completely or minimizing the app?

Comment: Exit the aap completely

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because the same Form instance is getting displayed.
In your start method you should see these lines of codes:

```
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
```

Just remove this or add a method to clear al text and call it before it is getting shown